# awk or perl to parse text

Tags: awk

I incorporated the awk (tried the sed as well) as part of a bash menu, but it just opens and closes right away.  I know I am doing something wrong but not sure what. Thank you :).

```
    convert() {
printf "\n\n"
cd 'C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\annovar'
awk 'FNR > 1 && match($0, /NC_0000([0-9]*)\..*g\.([0-9]+)(.)>(.)/, a) { print a[1], a[2], a[2], a[3], a[4] }' OFS='\t' ${id}.txt 
    *) convert ;;
esac
}


 convert() {
 printf "\n\n"
 cd 'C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\annovar'
 t=$'\t'
 s='NC_000013.10:g.20763477C>G\nNC_00001.10:g.20763477C>G\n'
 printf "$s" | sed -r -n -e "s/^NC_0{4,}([0-9]+)\.[^.]*\.([0-9]+).*([A-Z])>      ([A-Z]).*/\1$t\2$t\2$t\3$t\4/p"
    *) convert ;;
 esac
}
```

Comment: This looks reasonable except that the `-f` option in awk implies a filename for the awk script. Your "inline" awk script should be surrounded with single quote chars , ie `awk 'FNR >1 { ........}' OFS='\t' ...` (note you don't need the `-f`). Are you getting errors or isn't the reformatting working? If so, you should include this information in the body of your question. Use the `{}` tool at the top left of edit box to format code, error messages, and sample data/output. Good luck.

Comment: a word of warning: if you happen to have "NC_000123" or other possibilities (ie, not always 4 leading "0"), you'll not treat those lines

Comment: Please don't completely replace your existing question. If there's an update, adding it to the end is fine, but if it's a new question - ask it as a separate question.

Comment: what would be your suggestion as to a better parsing alternative?  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gawk` can do it:

```
$ gawk 'FNR > 1 && match($0, /NC_0000([0-9]*)\..*g\.([0-9]+)(.)>(.)/, a)
{ print a[1], a[2], a[2], a[3], a[4] }' OFS='\t' input
13  20763477    20763477    C   G
1   20763477    20763477    C   G
```

Comment: This answer works with **gawk**, but not **awk**.  This is because while gawk permits a third argument to `match()` as a target array, traditional awk (as found in FreeBSD, NetBSD, OSX, etc) does not. If you're going to provide answers that are version-specific, it's a good idea to mention the version you're using, and of course to test your solutions a little more widely.

Comment: @ghoti: Thanks for the information; I have to admit that my experience with non-GNU awk is rather limited.

Answer (score 2):

How about using regular expressions to extract the bits you want?

```
#!/usr/perl/bin
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    #skip to next row if doesn't start with NC_0000
    next unless m/^NC_0000/; 
    #extract digits after NC_0000
    my ($NC_num)  = (m/NC_0000(\d+)/);
    #extract 1 or more digits after 'g.'
    my ($g_num)   = (m/g\.(\d+)/);
    #extract a single letter, either side of '>' 
    my (@letters) = (m/\d(\w)\>(\w)/);
    print join( "\t", $NC_num, $g_num, $g_num, @letters, ), "\n";
}

__DATA__
NC_000013.10:g.20763477C>G
NC_00001.10:g.20763477C>G
```

Perl and awk are both quite capable text parsers. *Personally* I get along better with perl. But that's more a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of tool should be based on your ease of maintenance in the future.  If you'll have a better time debugging awk, then use awk, because fixing things that are broken is way more costly than slightly inelegant code or the odd wasted CPU cycle.

If you are looking for altnernatives, then heck, you could do this with sed.  I like sed because it's *short*.  If you have a regex parser already installed in your hind brain, then it's often the most efficient to debug as well.  :)

```
$ t=$(printf '\t')
$ s='NC_000013.10:g.20763477C>G\nNC_00001.10:g.20763477C>G\n'
$ printf "$s" | sed -r -n -e "s/^NC_0{4,}([0-9]+)\.[^.]*\.([0-9]+).*([A-Z])>([A-Z]).*/\1$t\2$t\2$t\3$t\4/p"
13      20763477        20763477        C       G
1       20763477        20763477        C       G
$
```

(I'm using a variable to insert tabs more obviously, but you could of course just add them inline.)

Comment: I modified the code and can not get it to run.  Thank you all :).

Comment: My apologies I will re-post.  Thank you all for your help :).

Comment: You should prefer `printf "%s" "$s"` to `printf "$s"` (especially when `$s` is an arbitrary string from an external input); in the latter, any `%` character in `$s` could be interpreted as a conversion specification by `printf`.

Comment: In addition, you could use `<<<"$s" sed ...` instead of `printf "%s" "$s" | sed ...`.

Comment: @musiphil, regarding printf, please re-read my answer; what you suggest will not work.  `$s` contains a *format*, so the newlines will not be expanded if you make it the data for a format of `%s`.  And regarding your redirect, that will only work if your shell is bash.  The question does not specify a shell.  My answer will work in multiple shells, not just the one you use.

Comment: @ghoti: I didn't catch the `\n`, but my concern for the possibility of having conversion specifications like `%s` in the input still applies. (C programmers could understand this better, from the danger of `printf(foo)`. Also see [Bash Pitfalls #32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#printf_.22.24foo.22).) My comment was more toward general cases, and I understand that it may actually not matter in your small example. For the `\n`, I guess you could try the construct `s=$'...\n...\n'`, though I'm not sure if it works in shells other than bash or zsh.

Comment: Yes, obviously if the fixed string with which I'm setting '$s' were to include formatting, things would break, and it's great to keep such concerns in mind. But I was only using the `printf "$s"` in this case to supply multi-line input to `sed` without having to create a temporary file.  This makes it easy to cut-and-paste lines from the answer to test the results.